# Alternative for std::exception(const char*) non-standard constructor

Tags: linux, visual-c++, g++, porting

My Visual C++ code uses the std::exception constructor that accepts a string and I'm trying to port the code to Linux / G++. What exception class should I use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSVC std::exception doesn't comply with standard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367545/msvc-stdexception-doesnt-comply-with-standard)

Comment: Kind of, yeah :-) My question-answer form is more terse. The question in the linked duplicate presents a whole lot of code making his question seem "specific".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Microsoft Visual C++'s `std::exception(const char*)` constructor is non-standard. While in the C++ Standard Library, std::exception has a `const char* what() const` method, it provides no way of specifying a string except by overriding.

You should rewrite your code to use `std::runtime_error` or one of the other classes from `<stdexcept>` as an alternative. Existing code that catches std::exception does not need to be changed, of course, since std::runtime_error derives from it.